# Ping a host and output in CSV format in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I have a CSV file named `ip.csv` in the following format:

```
Host,Status
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.4
```

I want to ping IP and save output in the same file, `ip.csv`, next to the `host`. Output should look like:

```
Host,Status
192.168.0.2,Alive
192.168.0.4,Down
```

When I executed below script, I didn't get desired output:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=',' read -r host status
do
ping -c 1 "$host"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then     
echo -e "$host,Alive" >> ip.csv
else
echo -e "$host,Down" >> ip.csv
fi
done < ip.csv
```

Please suggest.

Comment: ‘*didn't get desired output*’ is not a proper description of a problem. How did it fail, *exactly*? Could it have something to do with the missing quotes?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I want the result should be displayed next to IP column. But i am not getting the result in the same format instead it comes in other line.

Comment: First of all, never use the same file as `input` & `output` simultaneously. Use something like, `while read ... do; process >> output.csv; done < input; mv output input`

Comment: `$ip` is not declared/defined.

Comment: @RD I've a hard time believing it's as simple as that. Your script has *numerous* problems. Please don't use SO as a code-fixing service: Describe the *exact* problems, and show use the *exact* code.

Comment: @sat: I have changed it now to host.

Comment: The requirement is such that I want  my output result should be saved in the same input file. If i ping the host the result should be displayed next to that host (supposedly,If host is int the A1 column then result should be in B1 coloumn in csv file.  please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using this changes -

```
#!/bin/bash
a=""
while IFS=',' read -r host status
do
if [ "$host" = "Host" ]; then
    a="${a}${host}"','"${status}"$'\n'
else
    ping -c 1 "$host"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then     
        a="${a}${host}"',Alive'$'\n'
    else
        a="${a}${host}"',Down'$'\n'
    fi
fi
done < ip.csv
echo -e "${a}" > ip.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Will try out this way tomorrow at work. will update you soon.